# Lumia 920 bricked after factory reset?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920

I have been having audio problems with my Lumia 920, people sometimes couldn't hear me. Before trying to bring it to the closest Nokia Care centre, some 80 miles away, I went through the trouble shooting guide on the Nokia website. It give the usual advice, which ended in a factory reset. I backed up the photos, etc, and went about it via Settings > About > reset my phone.

It seemed to work as expected, showed cogs turning, so I went out to the shopping centre for a couple of hours. Came back and the cogs were still turning. A quick search online said that it shouldn't be the case, it's just too long. So numerous advice has been followed, from

> Volume Down + Power

to

> Volume Down + Power + Camera

to a sequence of

> Volume Up, Volume Down, Power, Volume Down

None of these worked. The best I can do is get it to the charging/low battery icon. So I let it drain, took out the SIM card and now have it on to charge. It is showing the charging icon, but it doesn't seem to be actually charging.

Is there anything that I can do without having to make the trek 80 miles away (or have to post it off)?

Comment: A soft reset can be dine by holding down volume down and the power button for ten seconds. This helped when my Lumia 920 was in the same state you described. http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/flow/item/16201_The_Windows_Phone_8_soft_reset.php

Comment: As you can see in the question, I have performed this action and still no change, still spinning cogs.

Comment: Normally Windows Phone does not changes when not "on". If you wait it drain the battery entirely and plug in the charger it shows the battery a couple of seconds (maybe minutes) and turn on automatically. So I feel you will need to get in touch with Nokia. Have you tried their twitter account?

Comment: Yeah, I've had to book it into their Nokia Care centre. No solutions. They pick it up today.

Comment: The same problem happened to me. Do you happen to have a Microsoft store nearby? I tool it there and they fixed it for free in 30 minutes.